# Javascript regex repeat optional group

Tags: javascript, regex

I have following regex to find url´s in css files:

```
url\(("|')?(images\/|img\/)?((\.\.\/)+|(\.\/)+)?(img)?
```

It´s working good so far except that I do not want to match if
`url(` is followed by `data`
Example:

```
DOES/SHOULD MATCH
background-image: url("img/home_bbbbbb_14.png");
background-image: url(img/home_bbbbbb_14.png);
background-image: url(images/home_bbbbbb_14.png);
background-image: url('images/home_bbbbbb_14.png');
background-image: url("images/home_bbbbbb_14.png");
background-image: url(home_bbbbbb_14.png);
background-image: url('home_bbbbbb_14.png');
background-image: url("home_bbbbbb_14.png");
background-image: url("../img/home_bbbbbb_14.png");
background-image: url("./img/home_bbbbbb_14.png"); 
background-image: url("../../img/home_bbbbbb_14.png");

SHOULD NOT MATCH (because of data)
url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,PHN2 ...
```

How can I exclude this case?

https://regex101.com/r/3mMdTI/2

Comment: what are you matching? the `url(img` only? or the value of the url? your regex seems to only get `url(img`

Comment: I'd go the other way, also to exclude something you need to use a negative lookbehind [**`background-image:\s*(url\((?!data)[^)]+\))`**](https://regex101.com/r/3mMdTI/3)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's a case for a [negative lookahead assertion](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html):

```
url\((?!data\b)("|')?(images\/|img\/)?((\.\.\/)+|(\.\/)+)?(img)?
```

or, a bit more optimized by using character classes and non-capturing groups:

```
url\((?!data\b)["']?(?:images\/|img\/)?(?:(?:\.\.\/)+|(?:\.\/)+)?(?:img)?
```

Comment: Hi thanks, this is doing it. I´m using it in grunt to correct paths in css after build. From your answer I got the idea maybe it would be better to just search for the image with a possitive lookahead like `(?=\/|\'|\()(.*?(gif|png|jpg|jpeg))` < not working ... anyway the task is running thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your regex duplicates different patterns, e.g.:

```
(images\/|img\/)    -->    (?:im(?:ages|g))\/
        ^     ^
```

Also you made all clusters optional:

```
("|')?(images\/|img\/)?((\.\.\/)+|(\.\/)+)?(img)?
     ^                ^                   ^     ^
```

which completely made your pattern useless. That's why I'd go with another regex to explicitly match image urls without being worried about what their paths are:

```
background-image:\s*(url\((?!data)[^)]+\))
                          ^ A negative lookahead to avoid matching data:***
```

First capturing group holds what you need.

[Live demo](https://regex101.com/r/3mMdTI/3)